# Single click event acts as double click event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using Ajax to submit the login form without refreshing the page. I've added a function to see whether the data returns 'error' (which comes up when the user enters an incorrect email/password). If it does not return 'error', the user has been logged in and will be transferred to the page within 2 seconds.

The problem is that my button acts like a double-click button and I cannot see why. This is my JS file:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#goLogin").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db-requests/db-login.php",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishLogin(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
        });
    });
});

function finishLogin( data , textStatus ,jqXHR ) {

    if ( data == "error" ) {
        $('.errorMsg').fadeIn(500).hide();
        $('.succesMsg').fadeOut(300).hide();
    } else {
        $('.succesMsg').fadeIn(500).show();
        $('.errorMsg').fadeOut(300).hide();
        setTimeout("location.href = 'protected.php';",2000);
    }

}
```

I've tried placing it between the document_ready tags, but that isn't working either.

Part of the HTML code:

```
<div class="login form">

            <div class="login-header">Please Login</div>

            <form method="post" id="loginForm" name="form">

                <label for="email" class="short">Email*</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required" placeholder="" />

                <label for="password" class="short">Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" placeholder="" maxlength="15" />

            </form>

            <div id="login-functions">
                <div class="loginbtn-container">
                    <input type="submit" id="goLogin" name="goLogin" class="button green" value="Login" /> 
                </div>

                <div class="login form actions">
                <p class="register account">Register an account</p>
                <p class="request password">Lost your password?</p>
                </div>
           </div>

</div>

        <div class="errorMsg">Incorrect. Please recheck your details</div>
        <div class="succesMsg"><b>You've been logged in!</b> Please wait while we transfer you</div>
```

Comment: Could we see the HTML code as well?

Comment: @Aurel300 My bad. I just updated my post :)

Comment: instead of onclick use $(form).onSubmit() and prevent default

Comment: When you say the button acts like a double-click button, do you mean that you have to double-click it, or that clicking it results in running the ajax script twice?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I mean that I have to double click it in order to show a response. So when I click the button once, nothing happens. If I click the button twice in a row, it either gives me the errorMsg or succesMsg response.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It could be a server response time problem. Try ZachLeighton's suggestion and see how it goes.

Comment: @JamesWong I've tried his suggestion, no luck. I don't think it's a server response time problem, as it's working perfectly fine as soon as I double click the button.

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3Xv/ - It registers the first click perfectly. Can you post a link to your full HTML?

Comment: @JamesWong Sure: http://dannyhtek.nl/mijne/inloggen.php (it's dutch though)

Comment: Thanks Danzerr, it's definitely a problem with your server side code. The javascript code is registering the click, you can also see a POST request going out in Chrome's debug tool > Network tab. It seems like `db-login.php` is not always returning a value.

Comment: @JamesWong Thanks for investigating! It has been solved. Take a look at the correct answer. I can't believe I missed out on that lol. Anyways, thanks for your time. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.errorMsg').fadeIn(500).hide();
$('.succesMsg').fadeOut(300).hide();
```

did you mean tto hide both? I see the `click` is working fine, though you should ideally do `submit`

Take your `submit` inside the form, and prevent normal form submit using `preventDefault()`

```
$("#goLogin").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db-requests/db-login.php",
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishLogin(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
    });

});
```

Comment: I feel like such a dumbass. I did not meant to hide them both, ofcourse. Changed errorMsg from .hide() to .show() and its working fine now. Oh gosh.. Thanks LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Please move your submit button inside the form closing tag first

```
<input type="submit" id="goLogin" name="goLogin" class="button green" value="Inloggen" />
```

The above button is placed after the `</form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because you click on input type submit and progress Ajax on it; it cause submit 2 times.

To avoid it, you can use as Zach Leighton said above ; or use as below

```
$("#goLogin").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db-requests/db-login.php",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finishLogin(data,textStatus,jqXHR); }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Pleas try put submit button out of form